# SingleChildScrollView + Column: either overflow or ignore mainAxisAlignment

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[SOLVED] I've updated dartpad with the working solution
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/42415ce855bfcdc148eb03872c170c77

---

run the code below on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/42415ce855bfcdc148eb03872c170c77) and resize the browser page vertically;

you will notice in the example on the right that

the [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) doesn't scroll and the [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) overflows

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const MaterialApp(
        home: MyHomePage(),
      );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Material(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Text('''without wrapping the column in fixed heigth
                   [MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly] doesn't work'''),
                  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) const FlutterLogo(size: 80)
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Text('''wrapping the column in fixed heigth
                   it overflow ignoring [SingleChildScrollView]'''),
                    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) const FlutterLogo(size: 80)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
}
```

before posting this question I did some research

[SingleChildScrollView inside Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57249935/singlechildscrollview-inside-row)

[SingleChildScrollView 'cutting' the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56664708/singlechildscrollview-cutting-the-screen)

[SingleChildScrollView is not scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624494/singlechildscrollview-is-not-scrolling)

[SingleChildScrollView inside Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57249935/singlechildscrollview-inside-row)

and either the case is similar, but incompatible with my case

or just dodge the problem allthogether replacing one of the widget with a different one

(with altered result for my case);

I tried wrapping either the column and the scsv with a combination of

[Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html), [ConstrainedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConstrainedBox-class.html), [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) and [SizedOverflowBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedOverflowBox-class.html)

without success, either breaking the app or losing the `spaceEvenly` property

I can use some help, thank you

Comment: do you need 2 SingleChildScrollView?? you can use 1 for the whole things

Comment: no no, this is just a code sample, I just need a column that "spaceEvenly" and doesn't overflow

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of SingleChildScrollView, you can give a shot to CustomScrollView like this;

```
return CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverFillRemaining(
      hasScrollBody: false,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // *  YOUR WIDGETS HERE
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Align` widget as the ancestor to your `SingleChildScrollView`  and give it the alignment you need to the children like this

```
body: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,  // Give it the alignment you need
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
            AnyWidget(),
         ),
       ),
     ],
```

Answer (score 0):

`SingleChildScrollView` widget must be a direct parent to the column or row, in your case the direct parent is sizebox widget. Now exchange `SingleChildScrollView` with sizebox. And it will work. You can see the whole code on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/42415ce855bfcdc148eb03872c170c77)

Change to this code

```
SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery
          .of(context)
          .size
          .height,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text('''wrapping the column in fixed heigth
           it overflow ignoring [SingleChildScrollView]'''),
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) const FlutterLogo(size: 80)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: I took a screenshot from your dartpad, it seems to me it's still overflowing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB6o7.png

Comment: may be your old code is saved, check it out my answer i edited it.

Comment: oh I see, you moved the sizedbox before the singlechildscrollview, but that way the column ignores the mainAxisAligniment !

Answer (score 0):

Please check it out.

```
   Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .45,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Text('''without wrapping the column in fixed heigth
                 [MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly] doesn't work'''),
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) const FlutterLogo(size: 80)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .45,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Text('''wrapping the column in fixed heigth
               it overflow ignoring [SingleChildScrollView]'''),
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) const FlutterLogo(size: 80)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: this way it ignores the "mainAxisAlignment", try changing the number of logos from 7 to 3 for example

Answer (score 0):

1. Set your row's item with a fixed height, should be screen width / 2 in this case.
2. use ListView for scrollable

```html
class SandBoxScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Material(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return FlutterLogo(size: 80);
                  },
                  itemCount: 7,
                )),
            Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return FlutterLogo(size: 80);
                  },
                  itemCount: 7,
                )),
          ],
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: your solution doesn't really "spaceEvenly" the children

Answer (score 0):

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.95,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                 Text('''without wrapping the column in fixed heigth
                 [MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly] doesn't work'''),
                 for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) const FlutterLogo(size: 80)
             ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: your answer is just copy pasted from @ismail answer!